Install 240v Mysa thermostat, but gangbox has 6 wires all colored the same
I'm trying to install a Mysa thermostat, which has 3 wires.  A load wire, L1 (L) and L2 (N). It looks like this:

My box has a total of 6 wires. I believe the 120 volt wires are twisted together (2 wires each).

Looking for help to know which wires to connect the L1 to and the L2 to. I know which wire is the Load wire based on the connection with the King thermostat.

Additional photos:

I can add more pics of the box if needed.

In what country are you trying to wire this and what country is the tstadt from?

@RMDman The bottom picture shows a Decora-style light switch, which apparently according to Google is a NEMA-only switch style. Going to guess OP is in North America or other NEMA-compliant location, probably split-phase electric.

@Triplefault, Yeah, I'm confused because some things looked familiar and some I had never seen in the US.  I was wondering if the OP was trying to use a foreign unit on US wiring.   It's probably just something I have never seen.

WTF the curly business with the wires. That's BAD. It's not cutesie, it's creating a huge magnetic field.

Based on the picture of the King thermostat above, the King is double pole, switching both L1 and L2 sides of the 240V split phase electric supply.
Based on the third picture showing one black wire from the King thermostat labeled LOAD BLACK, and the second picture showing both "LOAD BLACK" and "4" black thermostat wires going to single wires in the box, as well as the red thermostat wires going to the paired wall box wires, the explanation of the 6 wires in the wall box could be: power from the circuit breaker comes to this thermostat through the double bundles of wall box wires, then off to another thermostat or other 240V load somewhere else. (This assumes that the King thermostat was wired correctly: a mechanical switch such as the King does not care whether LINE or LOAD are wired as they're supposed to. If LINE and LOAD were swapped on the King, it would still work fine.)
Based on the online instruction manual from Mysa, it appears that the Mysa thermostat will be wired single-pole, only switching one side of the heaters.
One side of the existing wall box wiring would be connected together with the Mysa L2(N) red wire, under a single wire nut, and  the other side of the wall box wiring would be connected: the double bundle to Mysa L1(L) black, and the single to Mysa LOAD black:

If you find that the Mysa doesn't power up, that could mean that the King was wired backwards from the correct LINE/LOAD markings, and power is coming in on the singles instead of the doubles. Simply swap Mysa's L1(L) and LOAD wires.

Thank you @Triplefault!!! That did the trick! You saved me at least $100.
To answer the other commenters, I'm located in NA.
